# operational reporting in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have read many statements that Power BI is made for analytical reporting, not operational reporting.  That is, Power BI expects the use of a star schema data model and measures (sliced by dimensions / fields).  Power BI is not made for operational reporting, i.e., we munge data into a single table (denormalized) data model with no measures and create a table visual using all fields from this table.  Is this true?  If so, what is a better tool for operational reporting?

Comment: Yes, this is generally true. Power BI is designed to perform best with a star schema, but you could probably get by with the denormalized table if the table is not extremely wide or you don't have millions of rows. Another option may be Power BI Report Builder, which may be better served for the type of operational reporting you are looking for.

Comment: See, eg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/paginated-reports/paginated-reports-report-builder-power-bi

Comment: From an implementation perspective, for operational reporting, I could use Power BI Report Builder.  Or, I could still use Power BI Desktop, and put the report into DirectQuery mode.  But, should I be putting this kind of workload into the Power BI service?  It seems to me that, even though we can do some amount of operational reporting in Power BI, the Power BI service wasn't really designed for that.  So, given that, what would be a better tool to use for operational reporting?

Comment: The Power BI Service is fine for this.  It's just the interactive Power BI reports that work best with a star-schema data model.  Still paginated reports, or Power BI reports in Direct Query or Import will work.